# Unknown Server Tag <cc1:asyncfileupload>

Tags: asp.net-ajax, visual-studio-2010

I recently switched my dev machine from Windows XPP to Win7.  In the process I also switched from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.

Unfortunately in opening my web app and trying to build/run it comes up with the error "Unknown Server Tag ".  The target framework is 3.5, and this tag works perfectly on both test and live webservers, so the problem is the environment not the code.  I have attempted to re-install the ajax control toolkit, as well as .net 3.5.

Not too sure where to turn from here, so any suggestions you can offer would be a huge help.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the DOCTYPE html add <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

and inside the form tag add Scriptmanager